# How to find the selector for webscraping in Java?

Tags: java, maven, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the statistics of a hockey game from a website. What I can to scrape exactly, is that if in the last games before that game the home team had won or had losen. So there is this [website](http://www.eredmenyek.com/merkozes/nBPiuHF3/#egymas-elleni;overall), and I am trying to get the information from the last column. I used the inspector in the developer tools and I guessed I should used the selector "span.winLoseIcon a". I think it is not the right selector to use here, because when I run the program the String title is empty.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class HockeyScraper {




public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eredmenyek.com/merkozes/nBPiuHF3/#egymas-elleni;overall").get();

    for (Element games : page.select("span.winLoseIcon a")) {
        final String title = games.text();

        System.out.println(title);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the website, it's not loading data directly, it used JavaScript to load data, so you can't scrap directly by that url. I check that it using javascript to get data by sending get request to http://d.eredmenyek.com/x/feed/d_hh_nBPiuHF3_hu_1 with some header info which is mandatory.

You can use the below code that work for me to get all the title score etc

```
    final Document page = Jsoup
            .connect("http://d.eredmenyek.com/x/feed/d_hh_nBPiuHF3_hu_1")
            .cookie("_ga", "GA1.2.1639955025.1491211513")
            .referrer("http://d.eredmenyek.com/x/feed/proxy-local")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36")
            .header("X-Fsign", "SW9D1eZo")
            .header("X-GeoIP", "1")
            .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .get();

    for (Element game : page.getElementsByClass("head_to_head").first().getElementsByTag("tr")) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(game.text());

        Elements list = game.getElementsByClass("form-bg-last");
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Title : " + list.first().attr("title"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are right, with your code we are getting some texts. Do you maybe know how to also get the title from the last column (Win or Lose)?